# Reducing vertical space before and after using align

Tags: spacing, align

I am currently having outrageous vertical space before and after I use align.

For a bit of context, I used `\onehalfspacing` to make my document a bit clearer. However, it becomes ugly when I using align. For instance, here is a picture of what it looks like compared to when I am using array (and in fact any time I need to write maths using "$$") :

[image]

I would like to reduce this white space when I use align, but I can't find anything relevant enough. Since I am searching for something that works anytime without always repeating the command each time I have to use align, I was thinking of creating a new environment, but I don't know how to make one like align.

Thanks a lot for your help !

EDIT : Here is the code I used to take the picture :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%---------------

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill} 

%--------------- 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}


%---------------

\onehalfspacing 
%\setlength{\parskip}{0cm} %not usefull

%--------------- 

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\title{Tests Overleaf}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I am using array : 

$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
    f : & A & \times & B & \longrightarrow & C \\
    & x & ; & y & \longmapsto & xy 
\end{array}$$

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I am using align* : 

\begin{align*}
    a \times (b+c) & = a \times b + a \times c\\
    & = a \times b + a \times c + 0
\end{align*}

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: you should never use `$$` in latex. It is hard to tell you how to correct the markup making over-large spaces if you do not show the markup. Please always include a complete small document that produces the image shown, add it as a code block to teh question so people can test answers.

Comment: do you have a blank line in the source before `\begin{align}` ? You should never have a blank line before any display math construct.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes I have one, but in my documents I don't and I still have a huge gap between my text and my equations.

Comment: having a blank line before `align` is an error (and will produce at least `\baselineskip` of spurious white space, you also get more for align than for `\[` if (as you show here) the last line of the paragraph is short. as it always uses `\abovedisplayskip` rather than `\abovedisplayshortskip`  but with no example code posted not really possible to give a definite answer just guesses of things you may have done wrong.

Comment: the space is affected by use of `\flushbottom` for example, there are so many things it could be....

Comment: I just edited my post, you'll see the previous code and an Overleaf link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never have a blank line before any display math, that forces a one-line paragraph with an empty white line before the display. Also `$$` is not supported LaTeX syntax so I changed that to `\[`.

As the line above the equation is short TeX can use the smaller `\abovedisplayshortskip` if the equation is to the right of the line end, however `align` is always full width even if visually narrow, so always uses `\abovedisplayskip`  You can use `aligned` instead in a way similar to you used `array`, `aligned` is more suitable than `array` as it sets the content in display math mode, `array` is designed for setting matrices of values, and sets each cell in inline math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%---------------

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill} 

%--------------- 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}


%---------------

\onehalfspacing 
%\setlength{\parskip}{0cm} %not usefull

%--------------- 

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\title{Tests Overleaf}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I am using array : 
\[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
    f : & A & \times & B & \longrightarrow & C \\
    & x & ; & y & \longmapsto & xy 
\end{array}
\]

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I am using align* : 
\begin{align*}
    a \times (b+c) & = a \times b + a \times c\\
    & = a \times b + a \times c + 0
\end{align*}

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I am using aligned* : 
\[
\begin{aligned}
    a \times (b+c) & = a \times b + a \times c\\
    & = a \times b + a \times c + 0
\end{aligned}
\]

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Alternatively the `mathtools` extension if `amsmath` provides a command that enables the use of the short display skip on specific displays where you can tell the previous line will not be close to the top line of the alignment.

You may also want to use

```
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
```

so `setspace` does not mess with this spacing:

[image]

Comment: oh meanwhile I found a bug in setspace package handling of displayskip....

Comment: you may simply want to do `\setlegth\abovedisplayskip{8pt plus 2pt}` or anything else that you think looks right

Comment: Well I like the look of `aligned`. I tried the option on `setspace` you used but I there's a bug, better not. 
Thanks !

Comment: @MatthieuJentile no the bug is there even without the option (and when I went to log an issue I found it was already logged and I had already posted a workaround) https://github.com/rf-latex/setspace/issues/1